# I am creating a full stack react and firebase project using my Mac. I keep getting a TypeError when trying to run firebase serve

Tags: reactjs, firebase

**My index.js code:**

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const admin = require("firebase-admin");



admin.initializeApp();

const express = require('express');
const app = express();

app.get('/questions', (req, res) => {
    admin
        .firestore()
        .collection('Business Continuity Form ')
        .get()
        .then((data) => {
            let questions = [];
            data.forEach((doc) => {
                questions.push(doc.data());
        });
        return res.json(questions);
    })
    .catch((err) => console.error(err));
});




exports.createQuestion = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
    if (req.method !== 'POST') {
        return res.status(400).json({ error: 'Method not allowed' });
    }
    const newQuestion = {
        body: req.body.body,
        userHandle: req.body.userHandle,
        createdAt: admin.firestore.Timestamp.fromDate(new Date())
    };

    admin
        .firestore()
        .collection('Business Continuity Form ')
        .add(newQuestion)
        .then((doc) => {
            res.json({ message: `document ${doc.id} created successfully` });
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            res.status(500).json({ error: 'something went wrong' });
            console.error(err);
        });
});

exports.api = functions.https.onRequest(app);
```

**I write firebase serve in my VS code terminal. Error message says:**

```
⚠  functions: The Cloud Firestore emulator is not running, so calls to Firestore will affect production.
⚠  functions: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'fromDate')
at /Users/BAYPLS.GUEST/Desktop/business-continuity/functions/index.js:38:46
at cloudFunction (/Users/BAYPLS.GUEST/Desktop/business-continuity/functions/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/v1/providers/https.js:51:16)
at /Users/BAYPLS.GUEST/.cache/firebase/tools/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/lib/emulator/functionsEmulatorRuntime.js:532:16
at runFunction (/Users/BAYPLS.GUEST/.cache/firebase/tools/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/lib/emulator/functionsEmulatorRuntime.js:506:15)
at runHTTPS (/Users/BAYPLS.GUEST/.cache/firebase/tools/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/lib/emulator/functionsEmulatorRuntime.js:531:11)
at /Users/BAYPLS.GUEST/.cache/firebase/tools/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/lib/emulator/functionsEmulatorRuntime.js:690:27
at Layer.handle \[as handle_request\] (/Users/BAYPLS.GUEST/.cache/firebase/tools/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
at next (/Users/BAYPLS.GUEST/.cache/firebase/tools/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:144:13)
at next (/Users/BAYPLS.GUEST/.cache/firebase/tools/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:140:7)
at next (/Users/BAYPLS.GUEST/.cache/firebase/tools/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:140:7)
⚠  Your function was killed because it raised an unhandled error.
i  Request to function failed: Error: socket hang up
```

**When I copy and past the createQuestion function URL in Postman I expect the terminal to write:**

```
{"message": "document z24ronfurnfou23r created successfully"}
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a couple of issues here. The error is saying your `admin.firestore.Timestamp` is `undefined`. After reviewing this Github [Firebase-admin-node thread](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-admin-node/issues/1827), it seems the best thing is to import the `Timestamp` function directly from `firebase-admin/firestore`.

`const { Timestamp } = require('firebase-admin/firestore');`

`const createdAt = Timestamp.fromDate(new Date());`

The other issue is you're not running a local emulator (or it can't be found), so the connection is attempting to access your *production* `Firestore`.

If you don't have an emulator established, you can easily do that using `firebase init`.

You can start it using `firebase emulators:start`.

Then you can connect to your local emulator:

```js
import { connectFirestoreEmulator } from 'firebase/firestore';
import { initializeApp } from 'firebase/app';
import { getFirestore } from 'firebase/firestore';
import firebaseConfig from '../firebase-config.json'; // <--- your config

let isEmulator = false;

const startFirestoreEmulator = async () => {
  const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
  const db = getFirestore(app);

  if (process.env.MODE === 'development' && !isEmulator) {
    connectFirestoreEmulator(db, '127.0.0.1', 8080); // <--- match your env
    isEmulator = true;
  }
};

export default startFirestoreEmulator;
```